# Expandable list only expands after second click

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nel_mo/epjrej64/)**

I have a list, but is does not expand on first click.
And then on the second click it expands and collapses in one move.
Cant figure out why...

Here is a snip of the JQuery bit

> ```
> $(".expandListHeader").click(function () {
>     $header = $(this);
>     $content = $header.next();
>     $content.slideToggle(200, function () {
>         $('.contentCol', this).fadeToggle(400);
>     }); 
> });
> ```

Here is another list where it did work, but Ive changed the classes. (cant use this one).
They are the same in every way ( 99.9% sure ) exept the class names were swoped out.
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nel_mo/g6qn6p9f/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a FIDDLE and updated your code.

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epjrej64/4/)

```
.toggle()
```

Seemed to work. And also has a nice effect without stumbeling.

Comment: My answer worked, but yours is cleaner. You win. Will give it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the style -

```
.expandListContent {
 display: none
}
```

Comment: This solution, will work as-well. Mine was just inline. Cool Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Ive added this  `style="display:none"` to the `expandListContent` section and it worked.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nel_mo/epjrej64/1/)**

```
        <div class="expandListHeader">
            <div class="Collapse">
                <div class="expandListHeaderRow">A</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="expandListContent" style="display:none">  <---    HERE  
            <div class="expandListContentRow contentCol">
                <div class="expandListItem">Abraham</div>
                <div class="expandListItem">Albert</div>
                <div class="expandListItem">Amber</div>
                <div class="expandListItem">Andrew</div>
                <div class="expandListItem">Arnold</div>
                <div class="expandListItem">Astrix</div>
                <div class="expandListItem">Athur</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```